# How to use stat_compare_means() on multiple grouping variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm relatively new to programming, so bear with me. I'm analysing some biological data, where the weight of mice have been measured across several weeks. Mice were allocated into 3 treatment groups: A, B and C. A is the reference group. What I want, is a plot showing the statistical comparisons of weight for each week, preferably with different significance symbols for each group. From the data it is clear, that the body weight of group B normalizes after 12 weeks, whereas group C stays high. I want to be able to see that statistical change on the plot. Hope that makes sense. For some reason I just can't figure it out. Here's my code, and how the plot looks

```
BW %>% 
  gather(Week, Weight, "0":"24") %>% 
  group_by(Group, Week) %>% 
  ggline(x = "Week", y = "Weight", add = "mean_se", color = "Group") +
  stat_compare_means(aes(group = Group), label = "p.signif", method = "anova")
```

[image]

Comment: Your plot shows absolute values e.g. weight in g but you want to show differences *relative* to a reference group. Thus, your test will see sth differnt than your plot shows.

Comment: What sections of the plot above do you exactly want to change?

Comment: I have edited my post to include an example of what I would like to end up with

Comment: Do you want to have e.g. ## for p < 0.01 in A vs B and * for p < 0.05 in A vs C? This a pairwise setup with two groups at each test, thus no anova needed.

Comment: Kind of, yes. Just with the same significance threshold. So ## for p < 0.05 in A vs B and * for p < 0.05 in A vs C

Comment: A statistical consideration here is that your data does not meet the assumption of independence, e.g. your weights at week 20 will have some dependence on the previous weights. As such, simply comparing the means at each week will not hold. For this case you should consider a linear mixed model. Following that, you may want to investigate the between-group differences in within-group change, e.g. does weight still increase at weeks 20+ for group C, but not for group A or B?

Comment: Iff the question is just e.g. is there a difference between the groups at a given time point, we look only at samples with the same time point so we do not need to care about dependency here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(broom)

# create example data
set.seed(1337)

base_values <- tribble(
  ~Group, ~Week, ~base_value,
  "A", 0, 20,
  "A", 12, 30,
  "A", 16, 32,
  "B", 0, 21,
  "B", 12, 35,
  "B", 16, 32,
  "C", 0, 20,
  "C", 12, 38,
  "C", 16, 40
)

data <-
  tibble(Group = LETTERS[1:3]) %>%
  expand_grid(Week = c(0, 12, 16)) %>%
  left_join(base_values) %>%
  mutate(Weight = base_value %>% map(~ runif(n = 10, min = 0.8, max = 1.2) * .x)) %>%
  select(-base_value) %>%
  unnest(Weight)
#> Joining, by = c("Group", "Week")
data
#> # A tibble: 90 x 3
#>    Group  Week Weight
#>    <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 A         0   20.6
#>  2 A         0   20.5
#>  3 A         0   16.6
#>  4 A         0   19.6
#>  5 A         0   19.0
#>  6 A         0   18.7
#>  7 A         0   23.6
#>  8 A         0   18.2
#>  9 A         0   18.0
#> 10 A         0   17.2
#> # … with 80 more rows

tests <-
  expand_grid(
    Group = c("B", "C"),
    Week = c(0, 12, 16)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    test = list(Group, Week) %>% pmap(~ {
      data2 <- data %>%
        filter(Week == .y) %>%
        pivot_wider(names_from = Group, values_from = Weight)
        wilcox.test(data2[["A"]][[1]], data2[[.x]][[1]]) %>% tidy()
    })
  ) %>%
  unnest(test) %>%
  mutate(
    label = case_when(p.value < 0.01 ~ "**", p.value < 0.05 ~ "*", TRUE ~ "n.s.")
  ) %>%
  left_join(
    # position of labels
    data %>%
      group_by(Group, Week) %>%
      summarise(Weight = mean(Weight) - 30)
  )
#> Warning: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
#> * Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
#> * Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
#> * Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

#> Warning: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
#> * Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
#> * Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
#> * Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

#> Warning: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
#> * Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
#> * Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
#> * Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

#> Warning: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
#> * Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
#> * Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
#> * Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

#> Warning: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
#> * Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
#> * Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
#> * Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

#> Warning: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
#> * Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
#> * Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
#> * Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Group'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> Joining, by = c("Group", "Week")
tests
#> # A tibble: 6 x 8
#>   Group  Week statistic p.value method                  alternative label Weight
#>   <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                   <chr>       <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 B         0        27  0.0892 Wilcoxon rank sum exac… two.sided   n.s.   -8.48
#> 2 B        12        38  0.393  Wilcoxon rank sum exac… two.sided   n.s.    3.93
#> 3 B        16        63  0.353  Wilcoxon rank sum exac… two.sided   n.s.    2.86
#> 4 C         0        42  0.579  Wilcoxon rank sum exac… two.sided   n.s.   -9.58
#> 5 C        12        22  0.0355 Wilcoxon rank sum exac… two.sided   *       6.58
#> 6 C        16        17  0.0115 Wilcoxon rank sum exac… two.sided   *      11.3

data %>%
  ggline(x = "Week", y = "Weight", add = "mean_se", color = "Group") +
  geom_text(
    data = tests %>% mutate(Week = Week %>% factor()),
    mapping = aes(label = label, color = Group, y = 45),
    size = 10
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This works great, thank you! Is there an easy way to define different y-coordinates for the significance-labels of groups B and C? E.g. y =45 for group B and y = 50 for group C

Comment: Just create a new column e.g. called `y_pos` of table `tests` and then do `aes(y=y_pos)` in `geom_text` instead of `aes(y=45)`